# gradle tomcat plugin not starting websocket

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle, websocket

I'm using the bmuschko tomcat plugin with this configuration

```
apply plugin: 'java' apply plugin: 'war' apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'

configurations {
    provided 
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral() }

tomcat {
    httpPort = 8001
    contextPath = "/"
}

dependencies {
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.6'
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1'
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.9.5'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-gradle-plugin', version: '5.1.0.Final'

    compileOnly group: 'javax.websocket', name: 'javax.websocket-api', version: '1.1'
    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'

    def tomcatVersion = '7.0.59'
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
        "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:${tomcatVersion}",
        "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}"
 }

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.2.5'
    }
}
```

But still get this error in Chrome

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8001/test' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

I assume that the Serverendpoint ist not beeing started. Servlets however start as usual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a problem with the gradle tomcat plugin. I'm using gretty now which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I started the server using `tomcatRunWar` task instead of `tomcatRun` task and it started working.